# out of memory java heap space issue because of resource leak

Tags: java, file, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am reading a JSON file using below code and getting java out of memory error:

```
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
try {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = br1.readLine();
while (line != null) {
  sb.append(line);
  }
result = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get below error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
```

Later I realized there was a warning of resource leak for buffered reader
so I added code `br1.close();` and warning was resolved. However, the issue of java heap space is stuck.

I even changed my file to a normal text file and added just one sample line to the file, but the issue persists.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: No, for the mentioned issue the file size is huge.But in my case, I even tried now with 2 lines file.It just reads first line and throws this error

Comment: Did you check the Jiri's answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't any memory leak, this is infinite loop. You're not updating `line` in the `while` loop so it will never be null. It will just loop until you run out of memory.

You need to put the `line = br1.readLine()` into the loop:

```
try (BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br1.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        line = br1.readLine();
    }
    result = sb.toString();
} catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
    // TODO proper exception handling
}
```

Also note that if your input is potentially very large, you may need to process it sequentially instead of storing it all in a string.